how to show QT designer app on ubuntu 22.04
I have installed QT6 on ubuntu 22.04 following this tutorial with exception:
cmake --install build/ --prefix /usr/local/

and I changed the configurations of qtchooser as explained here, now I'm able to launch QT6 designer from terminal, but I can't see the app or its icon along with other apps on my system, can you please tell me how can I solve that? thanks.

Which specific icon are you talking about?

@ekhumoro this one, I might have to add a file to create the app link inside apps with this icon

But where is the icon missing from?

@ekhumoro qtdesigner app is missing from apps panel

Sounds like you need to create a desktop file.
